# php preg_replace issue in making seo links from post title

Tags: php, regex, string

i made a function for making a keywords from the post title and replace each word in the full post.

this is my function

```
function myseonew($title,$text){
$title = stripslashes($title);
$text = stripslashes($text);    
$fburl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$keywords = explode(" ",$title);
$regex = '/('.implode('|', $keywords).')/i';
$output = preg_replace($regex, '<a id="smalltext" href="'.$fburl.'">\\1</a>', $text);
return $output;
}
```

but i faced a problem for the output the characters all of it comes ( �������� ).

so is there any way to solve this issue

by the way my encoding is UTF-8

regards

Comment: Why are you using `stripslashes`? It usually means you are doing something very wrong somewhere else.

Comment: the stripslashes is not the problem even if i remove it the issue still

Comment: could you show us one or multiple example inputs (both `$title` and `$text`)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do-- what you expect that function to do. Can you explain in human terms what your output should be. Include sample input and (desired) output please.

Answer (score 0):

try using u modifier in your regexp:

```
$regex = '/('.implode('|', $keywords).')/iu';
```